# Why I get SocketException when downloading a page if I don't open Fiddler?

Tags: c#, fiddler, socketexception

I'm experiencing a weird situation.I have a method that downloads a page like following:

```
public static bool DownloadPageContent(string url, 
                                       out string content,  
                                       ref int statusCode, 
                                       CookieContainer cookie = null, 
                                       int maxAttempt = 1, 
                                       Encoding encoding = null)
{
      int i = 0;
      using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
      {
            if (encoding != null)
                client.Encoding = encoding;

            while (i < maxAttempt)
            {
                try
                {
                      i++;
                      if (cookie != null) 
                           client.CookieContainer = cookie;
                      client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
                      content = client.DownloadString(url);
                      statusCode = 200;
                      return true;
                 }
                 catch(WebException ex)
                 {    
                       /* some error handling code*/
                        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex);

                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                       _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex);
                  }
            }
            content = "";
            return false;
}
```

And this is the `StackTrace`, it happens in line `content = client.DownloadString(url)`:

> System.Net.WebException: **Can't connect to remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xxx.xxx.xxx:80**] 
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) +208ı xxx.xxx.xxx:80
>          konum: System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>          konum: System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress&
>   address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Exception& exception)
>          --- İç özel durum yığını izlemesinin sonu ---
>          konum: System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
>          konum: System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
>          konum: System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
>          konum: Kokoshome_Product_Downloader.Helpers.SiteHelpers.DownloadPageContent(String
>   url, String& content, Int32& statusCode, CookieContainer cookie, Int32
>   maxAttempt, Encoding encoding)

The weird thing is, if I open `Fiddler2` and run the program, it just works well! This code used to work, and I have been using [`Fiddler`](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for some time and as far as I remember I haven't changed any options.But now there is something wrong and I can't figure out. So what can be the problem?

Note: I have no other problem about my internet connection.I can connect the internet without `Fiddler`. And my operation system is `Windows 8.1`.

**UPDATE**

I got the same exception when I try to connect `MySQL` database and the `FTP` server.And that didn't work with `Fiddler` either. I have done some research and find the info about the error in [Windows Sockets Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **WSAEACCES**
>   10013
>
> **Permission denied.** An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions. An example is using a broadcast
>   address for sendto without broadcast permission being set using
>   setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST). Another possible reason for the WSAEACCES
>   error is that when the bind function is called (on Windows NT 4.0 with
>   SP4 and later), another application, service, or kernel mode driver is
>   bound to the same address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access
>   is a new feature of Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later, and is
>   implemented by using the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option.

But I still have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In virtually all cases, this means that your Firewall is blocking your program's access to the network. When you use Fiddler, the request bypasses the Firewall on the way to Fiddler, and then bypasses the Firewall because you have a Firewall exemption allowing Fiddler access to the Internet.

Comment: it seems that was the problem. I changed my firewall options from `Automatic` to `Allow Access` now it works. It's still weird why `Automatic` access blocks my program...